# How to calculate marginal effects for plm models

Tags: r, regression, plm

I wish to obtain marginal effects for covariates that are in my `plm` models in first differences with interacted variables. For my `lm` and `glm` models I am using the `margins` package and its functions. However, this method does not seem to work with panel models.

What alternatives do I have?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

In the absence of any viable solution I would calculate by hand the marginal effects at specific values of the relevant covariables. Ideally I would like to do so in a faster way.

Comment: package `margins` does not support plm models, see here: https://github.com/leeper/margins/issues/3

Comment: But is there some package that does the job?

Comment: No package so far. Open issue for years.

Comment: Actually, I was just using the ```margins``` function after a ```plm``` and it worked fine. Could you maybe specify the error messages that you get?